# How to Solve modulo using recursion(can't use *, %, / or Math operator)

Tags: javascript, recursion

Below is my code which works perfectly fine, except that I am not allowed to use '*' operator. But in that case, I don't know how to convert the negative number to positive for comparison. One option is to use Math.abs but I am not allowed to use that either.

```
var modulo = function(x, y) {

    if ( x === 0 && y ===0 ) return NaN;
    if ( x === y ) return 0;
    if ( x === 0 ) return 0;
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
        return x < y ? x : modulo(x-y,y);    
    }

    if ( x < 0 && y < 0 ) {

        return x*-1 < y*-1 ? x : modulo(x-y,y);
    }

    if( x > 0 && y < 0 ) {
        return x < y*-1 ? x : modulo(x+y,y);    
    }

    if ( x < 0 && y >0) {
        return x*-1 < y ? x : modulo(x+y,y);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flip a number's sign by either using the unary minus operator (`-value`) or by subtracting the number from zero (`0 - value`).

Either way, it's possible to implement modulo in a considerably less verbose way than you're doing now:

```js
var modulo = function(x, y) {
    if (y === 0) { return NaN; }

    if (x < 0) { return -modulo(-x,  y); }  // -27 %  4  -> -(27 % 4)

    if (y < 0) { return  modulo( x, -y); }  //  27 % -4  ->   27 % 4

    if (x < y) { return  x; }
    
    return modulo(x - y, y);
};

console.log(modulo( 27,  4));  //  3
console.log(modulo(-27,  4));  // -3
console.log(modulo( 27, -4));  //  3
console.log(modulo(-27, -4));  // -3
console.log(modulo(-32,  8));  //  0
```

Just for bonus points, here's an implementation for the "true" mathematical modulo, also implemented without `/`, `*`, or `%`:

```js
var mathModulo = function(x, y) {
    if (y <= 0) { return NaN; }

    if (x >= 0 && x < y) { return x; }
    
    return mathModulo(x - (x > 0 ? y : -y), y);
};

console.log(mathModulo( 27,  4));   // 3
console.log(mathModulo(-27,  4));   // 1
console.log(mathModulo( 27, -4));   // NaN
console.log(mathModulo(-27, -4));   // NaN
console.log(mathModulo(-32,  8));   // 0
```

Comment: Nice catch, I was just going to ask about that comment

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in Brainfuck and there you only have increment, decrement and while not-zero. Here is how you do it with that:

```js
function modulo(n, m) {
  function helper(acc, steps, diff) {
    if (steps === 0) {
      return helper(acc, m, 0);
    } else if( acc === 0 ) {
      return diff;
    } else {
      return helper(acc - 1, steps - 1, diff + 1);
    }
  }
  return helper(n, m, 0);
}

console.log(12 % 5);
console.log(modulo(12, 5));
```

I imagine you can do something like this to change from negative to positive:

```
function negToPos(a, b = 0) {
  return a === 0 ? b : negToPos(a+1, b+1);
}
```

Here is how it looks like in Brainfuck:

```bf
[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]
```

Argument passing is like the current cell and the next contains the divident and divizor and you get the modulus in the third and divide in the fourth. Imagine I've done sqrt and made a lisp interpreter in this :-O

You won't get a divide by zero with any of these but it will keep you warm during the winter. (requires ES6 since it will blow the stack with no TCO)

**UPDATE** At the time of writing there are no ES6 implementation that I know of. There are only partially complete and some of the features will misbehave compared to the standard. One of the features that most implementation lack is TCO but that doesn't make my ES6 statement wrong since they are not ES6 implementations if not 100% standards compliant. For the not yet ES6 implementations you can see what part if the language they have cared to implement in the [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: As of now, very few JS implemeentations have TCO, so simply having ES6 is not a sufficient condition for that. Of course, all of the answers here would blow the stack at some point.

Comment: @JLRishe Absolutely all standards compliant ES6 engines do TCO since it's in the standard. When that said there are few ES6 engines in the world. Babel does not implement ES6 TCO so ES6 transpiled by Babel and run on a ES5 engive would not give you 100% ES6 compliance even though Babel could have fixed this with trampolines. It's the standard you should care about, not the implementations around.

Comment: Ok, then at best the comment at the end of your answer is highly misleading because Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Node are all generally considered to support ES6 (because they implement almost all of its features). Someone reading your comment would be led to believe that your code would not have an issue in Chrome when it does.

Comment: _"It's the standard you should care about, not the implementations around."_ Ok, that's all well and good, but actually running the code requires using some implementation and people reading your answer may not have perfect knowledge re: the state of TCO support.

Comment: @JLRishe If Google states they have a ES6 engine and it doesn't do all the requirements then they are lying! It's like Scheme implementations that lack `call/cc`. They are a similar dialect but *not* ES6/Scheme. In a different Q I've had the opposite stance on TCO because most implementations in CL does support it but CL standard does not require it. In that case a tail recursive function is O(n) space but might be O(1) in some dialect that extend the standard, but you cannot rely on it.

Comment: I have no idea whether Google states they have an ES6 engine and that has nothing to do the issue here. The issue is that most people out here in the real world believe that Chrome has an ES6 engine, and so in the absence of some kind of qualification on that matter, your comment is misleading to most people.

Comment: @JLRishe I've added some info. People need to stop assuming.

Comment: Nobody has perfect knowledge. The purpose of SO is to guide people, not to give the minimal amount of information & leave them to make sense of it. And with your new edit, it now sounds like your answer is unusable (_"requires ES6"_ ... _"At the time of writing there are no ES6 implementation that I know of"_) and this isn't true because there _are_ some JS implementations that support TCO and that should be all that's needed in order for your answer to work. Why the need to be such a sourpuss just because the current state of affairs doesn't line up with your idealistic expectations?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the negation operator. For example:

```
if ( x < 0 && y < 0 ) {

    return -x < -y ? x : modulo(x-y,y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. You basically only have a few cases:

- If `y` is `0`, return `NaN`
- If `y` is negative, transform to positive.
- If `x` is negative, answer is -modulo(-x, y)
- If `x` is less than `y`, then the answer is `x`.
- Otherwise, the answer is the same as `x - y` modulo `y` (this is the recursive part)

```js
var modulo = function(x, y) {
    if (y === 0) return NaN;
    
    if (y < 0) y = -y;
    if (x < 0) return -modulo(-x, y);
    
    if (x < y) return x;
    return modulo(x - y, y);
};

console.log(modulo(4, 3), modulo(4, 3) === 4 % 3) // 1, true
console.log(modulo(-4, 3), modulo(-4, 3) === -4 % 3) // -1, true
console.log(modulo(4, -3), modulo(4, -3) === 4 % -3) // 1, true
console.log(modulo(-4, -3), modulo(-4, -3) === -4 % -3) // -1, true
```